# EdExcel GCSE question about Hannah and the sweets: show that $n^2-n=90$

Tags: probability, quadratics

This is my reconstruction of the EdExcel GCSE question that has caused such a [Twitter storm](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/education-33017299) in the UK in the last 24 hours, along with its solution.

---

Hannah has a bag containing $n$ sweets, 6 of which are orange. She eats two sweets at random from the bag.

The probability that the two sweets Hannah eats are both orange is $\frac{1}{3}$. Show that $n^2 - n = 90$.

---

Possible follow-up (I don't know if this was part of the original): how many sweets were there in total in the bag?

Comment: If this is an exam question, which age/grade level is the exam for? It doesn't immediately look like something that ought to be able to cause a "Twitter storm".

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's an exam question for GCSE level, which is for 16-year-olds. The Twitter storm was over whether it's too hard for this level. It seems to me, based on my experience, to be at the hard end of the GCSE scale, but probably not off the end of it.

Comment: Hmm, at 16 aren't you supposed to be above the age where you need to be bribed with cutesy stories about kids eating sweets in order to "motivate" you to do math? I would understand better if the storm was about how completely inane that framing story is. What's the point of phrasing something as a word problem if the story you come up with has nothing to do with anything you might ever want to calculate in real life _anyway_?

Comment: Cynically I would guess that many students have trained themselves to see a quadratic equation like $n^2-n = 90$ as something reflexively to be solved.  Making it the end result of a different calculation is fairly atypical, and that makes it "impossibly hard" because it actually requires being able to read :P.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It appears to be a wolf in sheeps clothing question, given the cutsey start then the sudden realisation how tricky the question is given how many assumptions you need to make.

Comment: @MrDobilina: Are there any other unstated assumptions than "at random" meaning "uniformly distributed among the sweets remaining in the bag"? That's the _default_ assumption about "random" which one would expect students at this level to apply without even verbalizing it.

Answer (score 6):

If both sweets that Hannah eats are orange, then of course the first one must be orange, and so must the second one. We can calculate the probability of that happening.

For the first sweet, there are $n$ in total, and 6 are orange, so the probability that the one she chooses is orange is $\frac{6}{n}$.

Once she's done this, there are now $n-1$ sweets left, 5 of which are orange. So the probability that the second one is also orange is $\frac{5}{n-1}$.

The overall probability (that both of these things happen) is then the product of these: $\frac{6}{n} \times \frac{5}{n-1}$.

Now, we are told in the question that the probability that they are both orange is $\frac{1}{3}$. So we have $$\frac{6}{n} \times \frac{5}{n-1} = \frac{1}{3}$$

If we multiply both sides by $n$, then by $n-1$, then by 3, we get $$6 \times 5 \times 3 = n(n-1)$$ or $$90 = n^2 - n$$ which is what we were asked to show.

---

As a follow-up, we can find the value of $n$, i.e., the total number of sweets in the bag. We need to solve $$n^2 - n - 90 = 0$$ which we can do by factorising: $$(n-a)(n-b) = n^2 - n - 90$$

We need two values whose sum is $1$ and whose product is $-90$. It is not hard to see that the values $a=10$ and $b=-9$ will do.

This means that there were either $10$ sweets or $-9$ sweets in the bag. Obviously there can't have been $-9$ sweets; so we conclude that there were $10$ sweets in the bag.

Comment: NB I fixed a small sign error ($x_1x_2 = -90$)

Comment: that's not completing the square!

Comment: @danimal sorry, yes, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution:

The probability that the first two sweets selected from a bag are orange if six of the $n$ sweets in the bag are orange is 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{n}{2}} & = \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{\frac{6 \cdot 5}{2 \cdot 1}}{\frac{n(n - 1)}{2 \cdot 1}} & = \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{6 \cdot 5}{n(n - 1)} & = \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{30}{n(n - 1)} & = \frac{1}{3}\\
90 & = n(n - 1)\\
90 & = n^2 - n\\
\end{align*}
To determine the number of sweets in the bag, we factor the equation $n^2 - n - 90 = 0$.
\begin{align*}
n^2 - n - 90 & = 0\\
(n - 10)(n + 9) & = 0
\end{align*}
Hence, $n = 10$ or $n = -9$.  Since the number of sweets in the bag cannot be negative, the number of sweets in the bag is $10$.

Answer (score -3):

The chance of an orange sweet being chosen the first time is 6/n. Everyone got that right.
The chance of an orange sweet being chosen the second time is (6-6/n)/(n-1). Most people seem to have got that wrong.
If the chance of both sweets being orange is 1/3, then n X n=108, but that's impossible because n must be an integer. In fact the chance of both sweets being orange can never be 1/3. The question is in error either deliberately or by mistake.

Comment: What's needed is the probability that both are orange. So we only need to know the probability that the second one is orange *given that* the first is orange. And if the first is orange, then there are now $n-1$ sweets left of which $5$ are orange; so the probability that the second one is orange will be $\frac{5}{n-1}$.